# How to download and install a .deb file

Tags: 14.04, deb

I have looked at several pages and still am not getting clear instructions on how to download and install a .deb file. Specifically I would like to download this one: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/libhal1/download

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you not using the repository?

Answer (score 21):

The package seems to be unavailable, but, very basically, here it is:

1. Go to the site you would like to download from
2. Download the *.deb file [here](http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hal/libhal1_0.5.14-8ubuntu1_i386.deb)
3. Go to the directory where you saved (Most likely the downloads folder) `cd ~/Downloads`
4. `ls`
5. if the libhal1_0.5.14-8ubuntu1_i386.deb package is listed,
6. `sudo dpkg -i libhal1_0.5.14-8ubuntu1_i386.deb`
7. input password, `y` and it should install.

Comment: For very new-to-Linux users, step 2.5 is: open a terminal (aka command prompt) with Ctrl+Alt+T.

Comment: @WilsonF I'd like to point out that a terminal and a command prompt are very different, but i should've included step 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Well, here goes:

1. Download the file by clicking on a link in that page - select one in your continent, preferably from a country close to you (you can look at the two-letter country codes like `es`, `in`, etc. to determine that).
2. Open the folder where the package was downloaded, and double click on the package file. It should open Software Center. Click on Install. Done.

Or, open the Software Centre - the icon looks like this: [image: Software Centre icon]

And search `libhal`, select the package and install.